# Schedule Job each 10 seconds - ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron, scheduler, sidekiq

I need a scheduler mechanism that will run each 10 seconds.
I use sidekiq, and that's why i wanted to use sidekiq-cron, but the smallest time unit is one minute.
Moreover, I need only one job instance running at a time.

What is the best practice for this situation?

By the way, we are using Rails 4.2, Ruby 2.1.2, Unicorn as web server and Sidekiq 3.

Thanks

**EDIT:**
I need it to run every 10 seconds

Comment: Does the start time need to be specific (e.g. at 10:00:00, then 10:00:10, then 10:00:20 etc)? If not, I think you may be better off with a long-running script with a suitable loop, running as a daemon so it can be managed (e.g. during deployment)

Comment: Regarding "EDIT: I need it to run every 10 seconds", there are a few different interpretations of this. Is it "*Must start at precisely 10 second intervals*" or "*Can start roughly once very 10 seconds*"? Is it "*Must start at precise clock times*" or "*Should run 6 times each minute on average*"? Just how strict is the timing requirement, beyond it being smaller than the one minute limit you are facing?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Sidekiq has scheduling methods:
https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Scheduled-Jobs

So you can do

```
MyWorker.perform_in(10.seconds)
```

Comment: This runs a job *in 10 seconds* (i.e. 10 seconds after the code is called). OP seems to want to run a job *every 10 seconds* (i.e. start new job routinely, six times per minute)

Comment: He can call it recursively, in MyWorker, to run it every 10 seconds.

Comment: I guess so. Better hope there are no bugs though (or a lot of code hardening) :-)

Comment: I need it to run every 10 seconds

Comment: And what? Recursive call will run it every 10 seconds!

Comment: But is it a good practice? is it the best option that available?

Comment: If I were you, I'd implement it as I say

Comment: @snoof: That is only going to be an opinion, and Stack Overflow does not really do opinion. This is a valid answer, but might not be the only one you will get. You can choose what is "best" later by selecting the answer that works for you. You can also use up/down votes and comments as a rough guide.

Comment: Not sure what the confusion is here. This is definitely the correct answer.

Comment: @jeffdill2: Relying on the worker to call itself in this way is fragile. For instance, it would be very easy to end up with no workers running at all, or multiple "chains" running at the same time due to failed attempts to stop/start them.

Comment: This approach is completely wrong, brittle and unpredictable.

Answer (score 1):

Use a rake task that runs in a loop with a 10 second sleep.  This rake task can create jobs that Sidekiq will execute immediately.

Sidekiq itself is not designed to solve this problem.

Comment: How can i create this kind of rake task?